# Change JSON structure from stored procedure in Java Spring Boot App before REST endpoint is consumed by client

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, endpoint

I created a Java Spring Boot application to call data from a stored procedure with a REST controller class to create an endpoint taking three parameters. I need to change the JSON structure before the endpoint's Json response is consumed by the front end client. Where should the manipulation take place within in the Java code? I am seeing examples using GSON and other libraries for JSON processing that are either manipulating a static json response or that of an external URL. I am working with a dynamic json response based on the a users submission from a form on the front end.

Comment: You can create a custom object and use it as a return type in the controller. Add the annotation @ResponseBody before the function return type.